# Debugger Error in Codeblocks : Cannot open file: ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks

`

```
Changing directory to: /home/gaezvr/Documents/ProgramacionEnC/StructsDynamicMem/StructsDyn/.
Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:
Starting debugger: /usr/bin/gdb -nx -fullname -quiet  -args /home/gaezvr/Documents/ProgramacionEnC/StructsDynamicMem/StructsDyn/bin/Debug/StructsDyn
Setting SHELL to '/bin/sh'
done
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
At /home/gaezvr/Documents/ProgramacionEnC/StructsDynamicMem/StructsDyn/main.c:7
**Cannot open file: ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h**
At ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:74
[Inferior 1 (process 9102) exited with code 051]
Debugger finished with status 0
```

`

I keep getting this error in Linux Ubuntu 22.04, with gnome terminal :
gnome-terminal --disable-factory --hide-menubar -t $TITLE -x

It's not showing anything the terminal, when i debug this code, happens with every code i try to debug, shows this in red: **Cannot open file: ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h**

```
int main (void)
{
    printf("Hey");
    return;
}
```